# Load balancing subdomains in Azure Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have two web apps sitting in my FrontEnd node type of a Service Fabric cluster. One app is listening on port 7000, the other 8000, but both ultimately sitting behind the same load balancer with public IP 1.2.3.4.

I would like to configure the DNS to point both app1.mydomain.com and app2.mydomain.com to IP 1.2.3.4, but the load balancer to route route app1 (port 80 or 443) subdomain requests to port 7000 and app2 to port 8000.

Is this possible, or do I need to set up two load balancers with two public IPs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I can add multiple IP addresses to the same Load Balancer, and associated different rules for each IP address added.